# What does APIENTRY do?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I encountered it first time and found no dedicated page on msdn. What does `APIENTRY` mean?

Comment: Show some *context*. Copy and paste some code where you've seen it used. It's probably a macro; have you looked at its definition?

Comment: It was in the entry point of a DLL:
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HANDLE hModule, DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved  )

Comment: This (`BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(...)`) is the prototype that VS adds when creating an empty DLL project - although MS states on [this learning page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/run-time-library-behavior), that the signature is `extern "C" BOOL WINAPI DllMain(...)`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

APIENTRY is an alias for WINAPI.

WINAPI itself is a definition for the type of [calling convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) used for windows API calls, the [stdcall](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxk0tw93%28VS.71%29.aspx).

Basically this is explaining to the compiler how to handle the stack and arguments when calling this function.  You don't usually need to worry about it unless you are making function pointers to these types of functions.

Answer (score 11):

It's just a #define for WINAPI, which is the standard decoration for a Windows entrypoint.

```
#define APIENTRY    WINAPI
```

Comment: I think WINAPI is also defined somewhere? What is the type of WINAPI?

Comment: @RajSharma #define WINAPI __stdcall