# DllMain() being called even when not wrapped in extern "C"?

Tags: c++, windows, dll, linker

In a DLL written in C++ (64-bit Windows), shouldn't `DllMain()` be declared as using C linkage, i.e. wrapped with `extern "C" { }`?

As far as I can tell, [this `DllMain()` method](https://github.com/appleseedhq/appleseed/blob/9b54406f9d92f1da87c7a1473be80cadbfa6bdd4/src/appleseed/main/dllmain.cpp#L78-L81) is using C++ linkage, yet it gets correctly called.

Is there some special case *somewhere* that would allow a `DllMain()` method with C++ linkage (thus with a mangled name) to be called?

Comment: You are showing us the function body.  Show us the prototype / declaration. as that is where an `extern "C"` would be placed.

Comment: DllMain isn't found via it's symbol name, so it doesn't matter how its name is mangled.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie There is no prototype or declaration.

Comment: @joshpoley That's interesting. How is it found then? Could you cite your sources?

Comment: The address of the entry point is stored directly in the DLL itself (see the PE/COFF spec for details). The linker has its own logic to decide what the entry point is, and can be overridden at build time (eg the `/ENTRY` option on MS's linker).

Comment: @joshpoley Except that DllMain isn't actually the entry point for a typical DLL; that would be _DllMainCRTStartup for things compiled with Visual Studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operating system does not call your code's `DllMain` function directly().  The DLL's own RTL calls it internally.  The RTL's real entry point is exposed in the DLL PE headers so the OS can find it.  The OS calls the RTL's entry point, which then calls your code's `DllMain()` function.  The linkage of `DllMain()` itself does not matter to the OS, only to the linker.

Answer (score -1):

APIENTRY is what's doing it.  It boils down to __stdcall.

See [the MSDN documentation for __stdcall](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxk0tw93(VS.71).aspx)  and [What does APIENTRY do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081409/what-does-apientry-do).

Comment: No. A __stdcall function name is mangled. The answer is as per josh's comment.